# blank value for attribute value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Suppose I have

```
 SELECT A,B FROM T1 WHERE A=X and B=Y;
```

The way I set it up along with php, I know there is a possibility that X and Y may be empty, since I am giving the choice to search with A and/or B. So let's say only A is given, what would Y have to be to return all tuples where A=X? Is there some kind of 'blank' function for SQL?

Comment: Do you mean `IS NULL` (like in `A IS NULL OR A=X`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return all rows where either or A or B is NULL (never filled in) or both A and B equal to something you defined:

```
SELECT A, B FROM T1 WHERE (A IS NULL or A=X) and (B IS NULL or B=Y);
```

If you were looking for something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: So just to be sure, if my Y is a variable $v, and I know it is empty and I do
$v = ""
this will be seen as null to SQL? Or do I even have to do that, can I just pass it as is?

Comment: @rex You can not **compare** to `NULL`.  `NULL` is not equal to anything.  In SQL your write `WHERE <whatever> IS NULL` or `WHERE <something> IS NOT NULL`.  See if this helps:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-null-values.htm

Comment: Ok thanks, was just unsure how SQL handled a PHP variable that was NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Given two search paramaters X and/or Y, you can use `OR` with `IS NULL` to search by either parameter:

```
SELECT A,B 
FROM T1 
WHERE (X IS NULL OR A=X) AND
    (Y IS NULL OR B=Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something of the sort if you know that the data in A or B will never be a NULL value or you can modify the NULL value in the if function if you know a value neither of those columns will ever be

MySQL:

```
    SELECT A,B FROM table where A=IF('X' <> '', X, NULL) OR B=IF('Y' <> '', Y, NULL)
```

SQL Server:

```
    SELECT A,B FROM table where A=IIF('x' <> '', X, NULL) OR B=IIF('Y' <> '', Y, NULL)
```

Your other alternative if your delivering your query via PHP is to not include the AND/OR clause for B if A exists, ie:

$querystr = "SELECT A,B FROM table WHERE ".($a != "" ? "A = $a" : "").($b != "" ? "B = $b")

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be looking to check if `A IS NULL`.

So the whole SQL query would look like:

```
SELECT A, B FROM T1 WHERE (A=X OR A IS NULL) AND (B=Y OR B IS NULL);
```

If the column `A` in a table is optional, you can insert a new record or update an existing record without adding a value to this column. This means that the field will be saved with a NULL value. NULL is used as a placeholder for unknown or inapplicable values.

More info: [MySQL NULL values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/null-values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean,

```
 SELECT A,B 
   FROM T1 
   WHERE (A=X or X is null)
     and (B=Y or Y is null)
     and not(A is null and B is null);
```